# How can i append JSON with multiple struct into array?

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift4, decode

In order to parse the JSON, I needed to use 3 structs.

```
struct AppleApi: Decodable {
    let feed: Feed
}

struct Feed: Decodable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let artistName: String
    let artWorkUrl: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case artistName = "artistName"
        case artWorkUrl = "artworkUrl100"
    }
}
```

But when I try to populate the array with that parsed data I got that message:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Result]' to expected argument type
>   'AppleApi'

This is my error message:

[image]

```
do {
    let appData = try JSONDecoder().decode(AppleApi.self, from: jsonData)
    print(appData.feed.results.count)
    var dataApp = appData.feed.results
    print(appData)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.feedReseult.append(dataApp)
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

} catch let err {
    print("Error",err)
}
```

And this is my array:

```
var feedReseult = [AppleApi]()
```

I probably need to reach to 3. struct to reach the array inside JSON in order to have same type of argument type. How can I do that?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You are trying to insert `dataApp` (which is of type `[Result]`) into `feedReseult` (which is an array of `AppleApi`)

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `feedReseult` should be this,

```
var feedReseult = [Result]()
```

and append the `dataApp` as below,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.feedReseult.append(contentsOf: dataApp)
    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Also i feel a typo, `feedResult` instead of `feedReseult`

Comment: I did what you said but this time it gave this error  " Cannot convert value of type '[Result]' to expected argument type 'Result' " . I really confused and don't know what i need to do. :(

Comment: @johndouglas yeah. just noted, you need to update the appending also. I updated that in answer. Now it should work

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really confused. I solved it

Comment: @johndouglas Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your struct from Json is not put together correct, you should just need one struct per one JSON load. Could you give JSON sample please?

If you want to Decode Feed which is part of AppleAPI then you should create an object that is of type AppleApi.Feed and put results into that.

Hope this helps a little

Comment: Problem wasn't in the structs. This was another challenge for me to construct the structs. Main problem was to append those parsed datas. Thank you so much. I solved it